# Use import in javascript being called from Java program through graalvm

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm, graaljs

I am trying out Graalvm for a use case and I was wondering if I can use import statements in the **javascript being called from java**. I have tried both:

```
context.eval("js", "import v4 from 'uuid';var o = v4();");
```

which gives the error
`Expected an operand but found import import v4 from 'uuid';var o = v4();`

and

creating a separate script containing

```
import v4 from 'uuid';
var uu = v4();
```

then running the script via

```
InputStream inputStream = Controller.class.getResourceAsStream("/script.js");
String script = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
context.eval("js", script);
```

which returns the same error: `Expected an operand but found import import v4 from 'uuid';`

I went through the docs and it seems like it is possible. Can someone please guide me towards the correct approach?

Comment: Given that the "real" JS import statement [needs a path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), that error is entirely expected. `import v4 from 'uuid';` looks like Node.js code, and you're not calling an exec for Node to handle this script. Either rewrite the JAva code to invoke Node.js, or rewrite the JS to use a proper `import` statement.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is still interested, the code below is tested with Eclipse running on Windows 10. (Note double escaped backslashes)
Of course, you should have both [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) and [GraalJS](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/js/) installed.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;

public class testGraalJS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Hello Java!");
         
         String src = "import {Foo} from 'C:\\\\Other\\\\foo.mjs';" +
                 "const foo = new Foo();" +
                 "console.log('Hello JavaScript!');" +
                 "console.log('Square of 42 is: ' + foo.square(42));";
         
         Engine engine = Engine.newBuilder()
                 .option("engine.WarnInterpreterOnly", "false")
                 .build();
         
         Context ctx = Context.newBuilder("js")
                 .engine(engine)
                 //.allowHostAccess(HostAccess.ALL) /*not needed for this example */
                 .allowHostClassLookup(className -> true)
                 .allowIO(true)
                 .build();
         
         try {
            Source source =  Source.newBuilder("js", src, "script.mjs").build();
            ctx.eval(source);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         
    }

}
```

Where `foo.mjs` is located in folder `C:/Other` with the following content:

```
export class Foo {

    square(x) {
        return x * x;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello Java!
Hello JavaScript!
Square of 42 is: 1764
```

Classpath in Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse classpath]

Where graal-sdk-xx.x.x.jar is downloaded separately from [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.graalvm.sdk/graal-sdk) repo.

[Docs](https://github.com/oracle/graaljs/blob/8044a00ed7d2015beecd8bdef07669650b8ec818/docs/user/Modules.md?plain=1#L135).

**Part 2.** In case you want to source Javascript from a file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;

public class testGraalJSfile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello Java!");

        // Therefore, any ECMAScript module should have file name extension .mjs 
        // Option 1: 
        // Use source file with extension .mjs like 
        // File file = new File("C:\\Other", "source.mjs");
        //
        // In case file is with extension .js see Option 2 below
        
        File file = new File("C:\\Other", "source.js");

        String language;
        Source source = null;
        
        // Alternatively, the module Source should have Mime type "application/javascript+module" 
        // Option 2: 
        // add following line: Source.mimeType("application/javascript+module")
        
        try {
            language = Source.findLanguage(file);
            source = Source.newBuilder(language, file)
                    .mimeType("application/javascript+module")
                    .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        Engine eng = Engine.newBuilder()
                 .option("engine.WarnInterpreterOnly", "false")
                 .build();
         
        Context ctx = Context.newBuilder("js")
                 .engine(eng)
                 .allowHostAccess(HostAccess.ALL)
                 .allowHostClassLookup(className -> true)
                 .allowIO(true)
                 .build();
         
         ctx.eval(source);
         ctx.close();
         
    }

}
```

See [here](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/js/Modules/#ecmascript-modules-esm).